Why can’t I hire new followers in Skyrim when I don’t have any current ones?
I recently finished the "Rigmor of Cyrodiil" Skyrim mod and tried to hire Marcurio, but he says he will join me after I dismiss my current follower. Same with Serana. The problem is that I don't have a follower—no dog, horse, or other NPC.
What could be the problem?

Have you misplaced your current follower, or did you dismiss them properly before?

I dissmissed one before starting the mod, when i completed the mod i deleted it, and when tryed to get another follower

There are lots of questions asking about bugged followers, have you tried any of those solutions?

Does this particular mod involve followers (temporary, permanent, etc)? If you go back to the previous follower you dismissed earlier can you ask them to follow you?

Yes it gives a follower at the start and when another later. No i cannot recruit anyone tried with serana farkas janessa mauricio

Does this answer your question? How do I get Skyrim to recognize I don't have a follower anymore?
